# COM Reference Count

Tags: c, windows, winapi, com, ole

Good day.

What is proper way initializing COM interface reference count ?

I see many examples, where reference count is initilialized to the **1**, but also see examples where is **0** set.

What is diffirence ?

Comment: Think a little bit about what a reference counter *is*, and you should be able to figure out what the difference between initializing it to zero or one is.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I expected that if ref. is 1, interface keeps in the memory. Its true? And if is it, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set it such way that when the last `Release()` is called the object takes care of itself. This most often means that when you create the object it must have reference count of 1 right before you handle the object pointer to the caller who asked for the object. Whether you initialize the reference counter to zero and then call `AddRef()` (before you handle the pointer over to the caller) of initialize it to one and not call `AddRef()` is generally up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is that your COM object has a *valid* reference count.

If you create the object, then it makes sense to start with a count of 1 (since one instance of the object has just been created).

You may want to read [this interesting article on COM in plain C](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C).

From that article, you can read (note the `exmaple->count = 1;` line):

> ```
> IExample * example;
>
> example = (IExample *)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, sizeof(IExample));
> example->count = 1;
> example->buffer[0] = 0;
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I read this article, but not explain why initialize to the one.